# Decode a token using DecodedJWT with HMAC256 algorithm in java - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, decode

Please help me on this, thank you very much:

I'm trying to decode a token received from a cookie provided by a service. The token includes username and email from a user. I want to get these information. How can I do it? I'm trying many instructions on the Internet but still cannot figure it out. My code is currently like this:

`String token = userCookie;

```
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
    DecodedJWT decodedToken = verifier.verify(token);

    String userName = decodedToken.getClaim("name").asString();
    String eMail = decodedToken.getClaim("mail").asString();`
```

I get this error when running the code: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm

Comment: The JVM does not find the `com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm` class during run time. Did you add the library (.jar file) containing it to the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I did. I rechecked the .jar file and it's still there.